# Magento - How to create discount code on a minimum purchase of some amount like (rs 1200)

Tags: magento, minimum, discount

Hi Magento experts,
             I am very new to Magento framework, I have some doubts in discount code creation. 
Using Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules i want to create one rule like 
discount code should be apply for specific products on minimum purchase of Rs 1200.

Discount Code should be valid when :

> Eligible discount code products total amount "equals or greater than" minimum purchase of amount(Rs 1200)

Answer (score 0):

Add New Rule from Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rule

In Condition tab this is how you will create you condition

1. +add : select Product Subselection from dropdown
2. click on 'Total Quantity' and change selection to 'Total Amount'
3. click on 'is' and change selection to 'equals or greater than'
4. Provide amount in text field(In your case provide 1200)
5. click on add button to further expand child condition
6. Select 'SKU' under Product attributes group
7. Provide SKU of your product in textfield and fill rest of the form(Action,Role Information), and you are ready to go